# Salesforce using Rails | Restforce gem | Error: Connection prefix not set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce, restforce

I am hitting Salesforce api using restforce gem. But on my local it is working completely fine for every case. But on staging server(AWS), it's throwing the following exception:

```
Restforce::UnauthorizedError · app/services/sales_force_methods.rb:23
  Connection prefix not set
```

Any pointers on same?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the client id (`SALESFORCE_USERNAME` environment variable) is set to the correct value.

Comment: This seems to be self-contradictory. According to the [Restforce](https://github.com/restforce/restforce) documentation, the client id would correspond to the `SALESFORCE_CLIENT_ID` environment variable. The `SALESFORCE_USERNAME` environment variable is for the username.